# How to check where rigid body will land before throwing it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a cannon and as the player adjusts the force applied to fire it, I'd like to show where cannonball will land.

Looks like the formula for what I want is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory#Uniform_gravity.2C_no_drag_or_wind however I'd like to know if this is something that unity can provide for me without coding the formula (as it's obviously already used in unity), one reason being i don't want to make a mistake where my calculation won't correspond to unity when the cannonball is actually fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Unity's physics isn't deterministic. I've seen a few teams trying to implement something like this. It takes a lot of time, and usually, one of the following approaches is taken in the end:

1. Using your own custom-written deterministic physics — but it's usually very time-consuming and requires a lot of changes to the whole project
2. Approximating the Unity's physics with special code — but it's not precise and can differ from the end result
3. Speeding up Unity physics, launch an invisible clone of an object with the same parameters and then display the trajectory it has taken — still takes some time to compute. Ask game designers if they're OK with the trajectory appearing with an "animation" that starts each time after player moves the cannon — the "animation", of course, would be the actual movement of an invisible cannonball clone.